# "Invalid constraint: the type used for the constraint is sealed" is invalid

Tags: f#

I'm wish to use F#'s type inference to infer the types of my code simply by the methods/functions that are called.

This CAN be achieved quite nicely by using extension methods of the form...

```
[<Extension>]
type AttributeExtensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member ``BroadcastOffset``<'a, 'b when 'a :> ``BroadcastOffset``<'b>> (this: 'a) = 
        this.``
```

when I have code that reads

```
x.BroadcastOffset()
```

type inference will kick in and infers that x, must indeed be of type BroadcastOffset<'a>.

A small fly in the ointment though is F#'s own types for example, if I write

```
x.Value
```

F# will not infer its an Option<_>, thats understandable, but I can use the same extension trick to get there?

```
[<Extension>]
type AttributeExtensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member Value<'a,'b when 'a :> Option<'b>> (this: 'a) = 
        this.Value
```

and that SHOULD in theory mean

```
x.Value()
```

should trigger the inference of x being an Option<_>

sadly this ISNT the case, because F# rejects the extension method as an invalid constraint because Option<_> is sealed and thus 'a can only have 1 solution.

True 'a CAN only have 1 solution but, in my book that does NOT make the constraint invalid, it is perfectly valid, just trivial to infer, and because of this overzelous rejection, I am frustrated in making "Value" trigger type inference.

any ideas how to get around it? (apart from changing the F# compiler myself).

(I can of course define a function 'Value' instead, but my intention is to use F# to infer types from "methods", and extension methods fit the requirement where simple functions don't...I have my reasons)

Comment: I must admit I am not sure I understand your problem. You want to define an extension method, such that when you use it, the type it is on is inferred as `'a option`? ie `let myFunc o = o.Value() // 'a option -> 'a` ?

Comment: is that ".Value()" from my extension method? - in which case, the extension method doesnt compiler....or is that "x.Value" the method defined on Option<_>,,,in which case that will not compile because f# wont know the type of x.

Comment: The questions I asked where trying to learn more about what you are trying to achieve, which is still unclear to me. I was able to run the code below error free. Hopefully what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got compile errors using your code and then factored out what I think you are after into a function, then used the function in the extension. This allowed me to call `.Value()` and it work out that it was of type `'a option` which is what I think you were after?

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

let v (x : 'a option) = x.Value

[<Extension>]
type AttributeExtensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member Value(this) = v(this)

let myFunc o = o.Value()
```

Comment: how very strange!..yes my code wont compile...thats the point...this is quite odd

Comment: "static member Value(this) = (this : _ option)" works too, I don't really understand why this is happening, but thanks